# Clip an ellipse in WPF - positioning off

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to 'cut' of part of several ellipses, in what is quite a big program. Since I had troubles making this work, I have started a new project in which I tried to solve the solution on a small scale. Again, I get some very weird results - which I expect have to do with positioning. Please see the below code for a minimal working example.

The program creates an ellipse, gives it a pretty colour and places it on the stage. It then proceeds to create what is called a 'RectangleGeometry', which we will use for the clipping. Please note that the geometry is placed at **0,0** with a width of 40 and height of 200. The result can be seen in the following screenshot;

[image: screenshot]

My end goal is this: to be able to place a RectangleGeometry at any position (lets say 200,300) and have it clip the ellipse at exactly that position.

```
Ellipse abcEllipse = new Ellipse{
    Margin = new Thickness(100, 100, 0, 0),
    Fill = Brushes.HotPink,
    Height = 80,
    Width = 60
};

DrawCanvas.Children.Add(abcEllipse);

RectangleGeometry clipRectangle = new RectangleGeometry {
    Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 40, 200)
};

GeometryGroup myGeometryGroup1 = new GeometryGroup();
myGeometryGroup1.Children.Add(clipRectangle);

Path myPath1 = new Path { Stroke = Brushes.Black, StrokeThickness = 1 };
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 204, 255);
myPath1.Opacity = 0.2;
myPath1.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
myPath1.Data = myGeometryGroup1;

DrawCanvas.Children.Add(myPath1);

abcEllipse.Clip = clipRectangle;
```

Update: Some more clarification might indeed be required; I want to achieve the following effect - as seen in the attached image. An ellipse is placed on the stage, it is rotated and the top of the ellipse is cut off. (In such a way that it 'respects' the new rotation and thus cuts at what is now the *new* top)

[image: ellipse example!]

However; this is the result I get when I apply the knowledge that "the clip geometry assigned to the shape will be relative to that shape;". As you can see, it doesn't really cut at the 'new' top of the ellipse.

[image: wrong cut ellipse]

Update 2: Added the code used to rotate the ellipse;

```
TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(40));
abcEllipse.RenderTransform = tg;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show an illustration of the image you _want_ to achieve, in addition to the image that you get now. Some other things to keep in mind: the clip geometry assigned to the shape will be relative to that shape; if you are trying to match a visual object with the clipping you add, you need to take into account the clipped shape's position (and any other transformation). Also note that the clip geometry defines what part of the shape is visible (i.e. the visible area is the intersection of the shape and the clip geometry).

Comment: It sounds like you're having a problem with rotation but haven't shown anything being rotated in your code.

Comment: Try using the [`abcEcclipse.LayoutTransform` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @Sheridan Thank you for your reply - I also tried this before (and now again to verify), but this produces exactly the same result.

Comment: Just thinking again about your problem, the only way that I imagine that you could get your end result is to clip the `Ellipse` *before* the rotation, as you can only clip horizontally or vertically. Alternatively, you could try rotating the `clipRectangle` too before clipping.